# How to find largest circle between disjoint polygons all enclosed within a square

Tags: computational-geometry

Let P1, . . . , Pk be a collection of pairwise disjoint simple polygons with a total of n edges, all enclosed within a given square. Find the largest
disk that can be inscribed in this square so that it is disjoint from all the interiors of the polygons Pi.

was thinking of using Voronoi diagram of line segments...

Comment: Are you interested in an implementation for a specific programming language?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the distance field `d(x, y)` on the square that defines for every point `(x, y)` the distance to the nearest polygon. Your aim is to find the maximum of this distance field.

A very easy approach is to discretize the distance field on a grid and find the vertex with the maximum value. You can also subdivide the grid further around candidate points.

But you can also incorporate a continuous optimization step. For this, calculate the discretized distance field and use the top vertices as seeds for continuous optimization. In this optimization, move the point, such that the distance increases until you cannot move anymore. This will find local maxima. With proper initialization, one of these maxima is most likely the global maximum.

To find the direction in which to move, find the intersections of the current disk with all polygons. If there is one intersection, moving in the opposite direction will definitely increase the distance. If there are more intersections, you could average the directions. You can either use a pre-defined step length or an estimate. To estimate the step length, find the distance to the next intersections (excluding the already found intersection primitives - not the whole polygons), let's name this distance `d_next`. You can safely move `(d_next - d_current) / 2` without causing a new intersection. There may be smarter way to calculate the step length.